# Laravel routes not moving to the next route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have two routes

```php
Route::get('events{event}', [EventController::class, 'show']);

Route::get('events/{eventType:slug}', [EventTypeController::class, 'show']);
```

and in the event controller

```php
    public function show(Event $event)
    {
        return $event;
    }
```

Basically I expect to have both `GET /events/1` and `GET /events/slug` working which it does with the above.

Now I would like to refactor the above routes to

```
Route::resource('events', EventController::class);

Route::get('events/{eventType:slug}', [EventTypeController::class, 'show']);
```

Now I receive `Error: 404 NOT FOUND`. Why isn't `resources` route proceeding to the next route?

If I change the above to below `GET /events-types/my_slug` works as expected

```php
Route::resource('events', EventController::class);

Route::get('events-types/{eventType:slug}', [EventTypeController::class, 'show']);
```

Comment: Try switching the routes around, so that the slug is defined before the ID

Comment: If you need to add additional routes to a `resource` route, those routes need to be registered before the `resource` routes. There's a section about it in the documentation for [Supplementing Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers).

Comment: @aynber that works for the slug but now `GET /events/1` returns 404

Comment: could try a prefix grouping? what are you expected ```slugs```?

Comment: @Ballard what do you mean by 'prefix grouping'? Basically I have 'events' of given event types such as 'weddings', 'retreats' etc. So each event belongs to a given event type. I would like to display the event type when a user uses  a slug and event when they use id

Comment: I see. Personally I'd make two routes for this: 
```Route::get('events/{eventType}', [EventTypeController::class, 'show']);``` to return all events with that category? and ```Route::get('event/{eventId}', [EventController::class, 'show']);``` while also using 'eventcontroller' to return an event model